# Process.MainWindowHandle is zero when executing .exe through batch file in win form c#

Tags: c#

exe application in winform window. when i call the .exe directly using process class, i got the handle and application get attached with form window. but when i call the same .exe through .bat  file using the process class, MainWindowhandle is always zero and .exe opens as separate window. Also WaitForInputIdle is not working thus i am using thread sleep which is working fine. the part of code is shown:-

```
              Process p = null;                
              p = Process.Start(@"E:\hude\test.bat");
```

//test.bat has following text:-     START "" "E:\hude\PROJECTION.exe"

```
           // p = Process.Start(@"E:\hude\PROJECTION.exe");

            //wait for the process to be created and enter idle condition
            //p.WaitForInputIdle(1000);
            if (p.HasExited == false)
            {
                string name = p.ProcessName;
                MessageBox.Show("Name = " + name);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            }
            //wait for the process to be created and enter idle condition
            //p.WaitForInputIdle(1000);

            //p.Refresh(); 
            // Get the main handle
            appWin = p.MainWindowHandle;
            if (appWin == IntPtr.Zero)
                MessageBox.Show("handle not created ");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("handle created ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The process object you are holding on to is the process that represents the .BAT file process.  Since the bat file spawns another process, you need to get at that process in order to check the main window handle.  You could use [GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the process spawned by the batch file.

Comment: no it doesn't work, using batch file i am aligning the .exe application in the center of the screen. thats why i have to go thrugh .bat only finally i have to dock this .exe in the winform.